# How to get global geometry of child widget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, c++17

I have label inside custom frame.
I try to movement of MainWindow (all aplication) on mouse event:

```
void settingslogolabel::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    if ((ev->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) && firstCIsNotNull){
             window()->move( mapToGlobal(ev->pos() - m_dragPosition - this->geometry().topLeft()));
    }
}
```

BUT! `this->geometry()` returns local geometry. 
So, how can I get global geometry of child?

---

What I try to make:
When you press mouse and move - all application should move as your cursor move, until you up mouse button. I want to make this interactive for label.

Full code:
HPP:

```
#ifndef SETTINGSLOGOLABEL_H
#define SETTINGSLOGOLABEL_H

#include <QLabel>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QMouseEvent>

class settingslogolabel : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit settingslogolabel(QWidget *parent = 0);

    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev);
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *ev);

private:
    QPoint m_dragPosition;
    bool firstCIsNotNull = true;
private:
};

#endif // SETTINGSLOGOLABEL_H
```

CPP:

```
#include "settingslogolabel.hpp"

settingslogolabel::settingslogolabel(QWidget *parent) :
    QLabel(parent)
{
}

void settingslogolabel::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    if ((ev->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) && firstCIsNotNull){
             window()->move( mapToGlobal(ev->pos() - m_dragPosition - this->geometry().topLeft()));
    }
}

void settingslogolabel::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    if (ev->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
            m_dragPosition = ev->pos();
            firstCIsNotNull = true;
    }
}

void settingslogolabel::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    if (ev->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
            firstCIsNotNull = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand the problem but, the global coordinates of the top left corner of a widget can be found -- from within that widget's member functions -- using...

```
mapToGlobal(QPoint(0, 0));
```

Similarly, the global geometry would be...

```
rect().translated(mapToGlobal(QPoint(0, 0)));
```

**Edit:**
If the aim is to allow dragging of the top level window then your `mouseMoveEvent` implementation should be something like (untested)...

```
void settingslogolabel::mouseMoveEvent (QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    if ((ev->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) && firstCIsNotNull) {
        auto delta = ev->pos() - m_dragPosition;
        window()->move(window()->pos() + delta);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, how I should put it inside `window()->move( mapToGlobal(ev->pos() - m_dragPosition - this->geometry().topLeft()));`

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't understand what you're trying to do.  Can you edit your question to clarify?

Comment: added. Sorry for my English

Comment: If I use local geomenty() - when mouse move - the entire application is teleported to another tap of the screen, and only then begins to move behind the cursor.

Comment: Works fine! Thank you!